# Array to nested Dictionary in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, dictionary

There are a lot of questions with similar title but no one answers my question.

In my case I have an array:

["1", "2", "3", "4"]

And resulting dictionary should be:

["1": ["2": ["3": "4"]]]

How to convert it correctly? As I understand `map`, `reduce` and the similar functions doesn't have such functionality. And is it possible to do without of writing a recursive method?

Both Objective-C and Swift are applicable

Comment: Weird question but interesting :-p

Comment: What is wrong with using a recursive method?

Comment: @DatNguyen, the recursion looks like extra for this task and it seems you also need to mark all the params as mutable

Comment: Does recursive method means just the forin loop. Does this 'recursive' here means enumeration also? Also I think, any solution to this is problem must use the recursion, i.e. iteration over the array, be it higher order function like map, reduce etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Swift solution, using `reduce`:

```
let a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

let d = a.dropLast(2).reversed()
    .reduce([a[a.count - 2] : a[a.count - 1]]) { [$1 : $0] }

print(d) // ["1": ["2": ["3": "4"]]]
```

Here it is assumed that the array has at least 2 elements.

In our example, `["3", "4"]` is the initial value for `reduce`,
and for the remaining elements in reverse order, a nested dictionary
 is created in the closure with `[$1 : $0]`.

The type of the result is `[String: Any]`, which bridges to 
`NSDictionary` if necessary.

Comment: pretty ! :-p love it

Comment: Thanks. But note - it won't work for `array.count < 2`. Could you fix that?

Comment: What result would you expect for an empty or single-element array? You can't build a dictionary from 0 or 1 elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
    //Your array
    NSArray *a = @[@1,@2,@3,@4];

    //Get the two last values (considering your array length must be at least 2 !
    NSDictionary *last = @{a[a.count-2]:a[a.count-1]};

    //In reverse order we assign last created dictionary to the current key, the array length must be superior than 3
    for (NSInteger i = a.count - 3; i >= 0; i--)
        last = @{a[i]:last};

    NSLog(@"My dictionary %@", last);
```

Comment: Yeah in ObjC it's possible, in Swift not. The type of `last` at declaration is different from what you are assigning to it inside iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simplier solution:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArr = [array mutableCopy];
while (tempArray.count > 1) {
    id value = tempArr.lastObject;
    [tempArr removeLastObject];
    NSString *key = tempArr.lastObject;
    [tempArr removeLastObject];
    [tempArr addObject:@{key: value}];
}
id result = tempArr.firstObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive option.

```
func toNestedDictionary(arr: [String]) -> [String: Any?]? {
    if arr.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
    else if arr.count == 1 {
        return Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: (arr.first!, nil))
    }
    else if arr.count == 2 {
        return Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: (arr.first!, arr.last!))
    }
    else {
        let head = arr.first!
        let tail = arr.dropFirst()
        return Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: (head, toNestedDictionary(arr: Array(tail))))
    }
}

print (toNestedDictionary(arr: ["1"]))                  
// Optional(["1": nil])

print (toNestedDictionary(arr: ["1", "2"]))             
// Optional(["1": Optional("2")])

print (toNestedDictionary(arr: ["1", "2", "3"]))        
// Optional(["1": Optional(["2": Optional("3")])])

print (toNestedDictionary(arr: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]))   
// Optional(["1": Optional(["2": Optional(["3": Optional("4")])])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines without recursion

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];    
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = arr.count-2; i>=0;i--) {
    if (i == arr.count-2) {
        [dic setObject:arr[i+1] forKey:arr[i]];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *tempDic = dic;
        dic = @{arr[i]:tempDic};
    }
}
NSLog(@"Solution%@",dic);
```

Comment: thanks but already posted the code with the same idea and even without confusing indexes

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using recursive programming easily. Here is the solution using Swift;

```
var ary = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
func recursive(array:[String]) -> Any {
    if ary.count > 1 {
        let key = ary.removeFirst()
        return [key : recursive(array: array)]
    } else {
        return array.last!
    }

}
let reuslt = recursive(array: ary)
```

And result is: `["1": ["2": ["3": "4"]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Given a list

```
var list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

you can write

```
if let lastValue = list.popLast(), let lastKey = list.popLast() {
    let dict = list.reversed().reduce([lastKey:lastValue]) { [$1:$0] }
    print(dict)
}
```

Result

```
["1": ["2": ["3": "4"]]]
```

> Please note that this code only works if the list contains at least 2 elements